# Login failure for collection user after migrating to Azure SQL

Tags: xconnect, azure, sql-database

"login failed for collectionuser" errors appear after migrating our Sitecore 10.1.1 databases from self-hosted SQL Server on VM to Azure SQL Database. The site itself is working, but anything connected to XConnect is not.

Mitigation attempts:

- Validated all Connection Strings worked in all three sites

  - identity
  - sc
  - xconnect
- Created individual collectionuser users and used the same password for each.

  - Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager
  - Xdb.Collection.Shard0
  - Xdb.Collection.Shard1
- Executed `EXEC [xdb_collection].[GrantLeastPrivilege] @UserName = '$(CollectionDbUserName)'` on each shard
- Updated the ServerName and DatabaseName fields to match the new server and database names

  - `[__ShardManagement].[ShardsGlobal]`
  - `[__ShardManagement].[ShardsLocal]`
- Recycled AppPools and Services

If I revert only the collection connectionString the errors stop, so I know that it is the connection to those databases is the problem, but of course, we want the databases in Azure....
Anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: collection_user access is needed in multiple databases. In each shard, I believe you will need to run this script ```EXEC [xdb_collection].[GrantLeastPrivilege] @UserName = '$(CollectionDbUserName)'``` and execute the output of the first script.

Comment: @NehemiahJeyakumar, I updated my question to show had done that previously. Examining the SP shows that it executes the script output after printing the commands.

Comment: I believe I got this same error when I did something similar. In `Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager` there are tables which have references to database names, e.g. `ShardsGlobal` has a `ServerName` and `DatabaseName` field. Is this all set correctly? More info can be found here https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/rename-an-xdb-collection-database-shard.html

Comment: @Jeroen, I had checked the ServerName and DatabaseName fields previously. They are correct.
(updated question to be more clear)

Comment: When I had this issue I only figured out what was happening by running DB profiler. Perhaps you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631093/4950874?